# Google api php client giving "malformed auth code" error

Tags: google-api-php-client

So I recently upgraded the google api client for PHP, and I've been having trouble getting it to authenticate and give me a token. It used to work fine with the old library, however this new library installed via composer has given me several problems. Here is my code for reference:

```
if (!empty($gp_auth_code) {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig('<path to client.json file>');

    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Oauth2::PLUS_LOGIN);

    $client->setRedirectUri('<redirect URI>');


    $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($gp_auth_code);

    $gp_access_token = $token['access_token'];
    $gp_refresh_token = $client->refreshToken($token)['refresh_token'];
}
```

Whenever I run that code, it gives me the response "invalid grant, Malformed Auth code."

Is there something I'm doing wrong? The $gp_auth_code used to work just fine, and the path to the json file definitely works, and the redirect URI is definitely there as well. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm basically trying to get access to the google plus profile's info, so we can register the user via google plus.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Node.js` googleapis client library, Here is my case:

The authorization code in the url hash fragment is be encoded by `encodeURIComponent` api, so if you pass this code to request access token. It will throw an error:

`{ "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Malformed auth code." }`

So I use `decodeURIComponent` to decode the authorization code.

```
decodeURIComponent('4%2F_QCXwy-PG5Ub_JTiL7ULaCVb6K-Jsv45c7TPqPsG2-sCPYMTseEtqHWcU_ynqWQJB3Vuw5Ad1etoWqNPBaGvGHY')
```

After decode, the authorization code is:

```
"4/_QCXwy-PG5Ub_JTiL7ULaCVb6K-Jsv45c7TPqPsG2-sCPYMTseEtqHWcU_ynqWQJB3Vuw5Ad1etoWqNPBaGvGHY"
```

Then, everything works fine.